# Carrier Identification Android - New carrier

Tags: android-wireless, carrier

I work for a cell phone carrier and we have our own SIM cards. Back in April we tried adding our carrier information to Android by following this [Carrier Identification article](https://source.android.com/docs/core/connect/carrierid)

I tried adding the carrier settings via this [form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1KjwTaExKRjkE9tbR9yavBrGzwvuz1dNku2Ae_7GrdUQ/viewform?edit_requested=true) but we got no response nor confirmation. Could someone familiar with the process explain what the next steps are? Do we need a contact from Android?

Answer (score 0):

First, you might want to double-check the form you submitted to ensure that all the required information was provided correctly. It's possible that some details were missing or there was a technical glitch that prevented the response.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I tried re-submitting the form with just the basic mandatory information but I still didn't get any confirmation. Is there a way I can check if my request is being processed? Thanks